# How to override function in WordPress Parent theme from Child theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

The parent theme has the following:

```
public function mega_menu_attributes( $atts, $item, $args, $depth ) {

        // Get Mega Menu Type.
        $menu_type = $this->is_mega_menu( $item, $args );

        // Mega Menu attrs for terms.
        if ( in_array( $menu_type, array( 'term', 'child-term' ), true ) ) {
            $atts['data-term'] = $item->object_id;

            if ( 'term' === $menu_type ) {
                $atts['data-numberposts'] = 5;
            } elseif ( 'child-term' === $menu_type ) {
                $atts['data-numberposts'] = 6;
            }
        }

        // Mega Menu attrs for posts.
        if ( isset( $item->mega_menu_children ) && 'mixed' === $menu_type ) {
            $layout = $this->identify_mega_menu_layout( $item->mega_menu_children );

            if ( 'posts' === $layout ) {

                $posts = array();

                foreach ( $item->mega_menu_children as $_post ) {
                    $posts[] = $_post->object_id;
                }

                $atts['data-posts'] = implode( '|', $posts );

                $atts['data-numberposts'] = 5;
            }
        }

        return $atts;
    }
```

I want to override `$atts['data-numberposts'] = 6;` with `$atts['data-numberposts'] = 12;`

That's all I'm trying to do in my Child theme functions.php

I've checked out several threads here that cover similar cases, but none of the solutions I've tried from them have worked. This includes:

- variations of removing the parent theme function/filter and replacing it, but nothing seemed to happen at all so I clearly didn't do it right.
- just adding the function voer again, but the parent theme doesn't use function(exists)
- `include_once get_theme_file_path('/inc/mega-menu.php');` and `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` to try and include/load the php file from the child theme instead of the parent, but am always met with "Cannot redeclare [function_name] (previously declared in...)

```
function remove_parent_theme_mega_menu_atts()
{
    remove_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', array( $this, 'mega_menu_attributes' ), 10, 4 );
}

add_action('init', 'remove_parent_theme_mega_menu_atts');
```

I'm like intermediate with PHP/WordPress and thought I could get this one figured out, but I'm just in over my head now as I couldn't get any of these solutions to work.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can you leave the parent stuff in place, add your own nav_menu_link_attributes filter that runs after the parent theme's filter, and overwrite whatever it sets?

Comment: @Aaron I did come across this solution, and gave it a shot, but wasn't able to get anything working. I just don't have the chops for it. I'm alright with the doing that, but couldn't figure out how to write it properly and make it work and is just a little over my head in how to override the existing filter. Thank you for the suggestion, I appreciate it.

Comment: There's not enough information here to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like this should work. What happens?

```
function test_run_before($atts, $item, $args) {
  $atts['data-numberposts'] = 12;
  return $atts;
}
function test_run_after($atts, $item, $args) {
  $atts['data-numberposts'] = 12;
  return $atts;
}

add_filter('nav_menu_link_attributes', 'test_run_before', 9, 3);
add_filter('nav_menu_link_attributes', 'test_run_after', 11, 3);
```

Comment: That did it! Used test_run_after. 

Thank you so much!!